# click two div but jquery .not() not working

Tags: jquery

I have two "Div",class **.bb** & **.ll**

I want to click **.bb** but not **.ll** to show alert('ok');

HTML:

```
<div class="bb" style="width:500px;height:500px; background:#f00;">
    <div class="ll" style="width:200px;height:200px; background:#0f0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".bb").not('.ll').click(function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

my code link:
http://jsfiddle.net/juornp65/

I try to use :not(),but it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **e.target** to get the current targeted element and use `is()` to check the `.ll` element

```
   $(".bb").click(function (e) {
    
        if (!$(e.target).is('.ll')) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/juornp65/1/)**

NOTE : `$(".bb").not('.ll')` it will filter the `.li` not a children

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do like so:

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).hasClass('bb')) {
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

*Edit*: better to use `hasClass()` as per @AmmarCSE's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783958/2788131) in case of multiple class names.

Answer (score 0):

Using `event.target`, check if it has the class with [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```js
$(".bb").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('ll')) {
    alert("ok");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bb" style="width:500px;height:500px; background:#f00;">
  <div class="ll" style="width:200px;height:200px; background:#0f0;">
  </div>
</div>
```